# list<構造体>に対してのソート

Tags: c++, c++11

```
typedef struct address {
    int number;     
    string name;            // 名前
    string phoneNumber;     // 電話番号
}Address;
```

このような構造体を用意し、

```
list<Address> addressList;
```

このようにlistで宣言してソートは以下のようにしようと思いました。

```
sort( addressList.begin(), addressList.end(), 
    []( Address numA, Address numB )->int {
    return ( numA.number > numB.number );
});
```

VS2017を使用していますが以下のようなエラーが出てきましたが、どのような意味となるのでしょうか。
又、解決策としてはどのようにするのが正解なのでしょうか。よろしくお願いいたします。

```
重大度レベル  コード 説明  プロジェクト  ファイル    行   抑制状態
エラー C2784   'unknown-type std::operator -(const std::move_iterator<_RanIt> &,const std::move_iterator<_RanIt2> &)': テンプレート 引数を 'const std::move_iterator<_RanIt> &' に対して 'std::_List_unchecked_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<address>>>' から減少できませんでした listSortTest    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\include\algorithm  2908
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`std::sort`関数](https://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/algorithm/sort.html) では `std::list<T>` コンテナをソートすることができません。代わりに [`std::list<T>::sort`メンバ関数](https://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/list/sort.html) を呼び出す必要があります。

```
addressList.sort([](const Address& numA, const Address& numB) {
  return (numA.number > numB.number);  // 降順ソート
});
```

---

> 以下のようなエラーが出てきましたが、どのような意味となるのでしょうか。
>
> > エラー C2784   'unknown-type std::operator -(const std::move_iterator<_RanIt> &,const std::move_iterator<_RanIt2> &)': テンプレート 引数を 'const std::move_iterator<_RanIt> &' に対して 'std::_List_unchecked_iterator>>' から減少できませんでした

`std::sort`はテンプレート関数として定義されていますが、エラーメッセージは「関数を実体化するプロセス途中で型の導出に失敗したこと」を表します。残念ながら、このエラーメッセージから直接原因を読み取るのはほとんど不可能かと思います。真の原因は「`std::sort`関数はRandom Access Iteratorを引数に要求するが、`std::list<T>`のイテレータはRandom Access Iteratorではないため(Bidirectional Iterator)」です。[こちらの記事](https://cpplover.blogspot.jp/2007/03/concepts-extending-c-templates-for.html)もご参考に。

現在(C++14)のC++言語仕様では、このような状況に対して適切なエラーメッセージを出すことが非常に難しいというのが実情です。将来的にはコンセプト(Concept)という機能が追加され、このあたりのエラーメッセージ改善につながると考えられます。

---

> このようにlistで宣言してソートは以下のようにしようと思いました。
>
> ```
> sort( addressList.begin(), addressList.end(), 
>   []( Address numA, Address numB )->int {
>   return ( numA.number > numB.number );
> });
> ```

上記でも動きはしますが、いくつか気になる点があります。

- 実行時パフォーマンスの観点から、引数はconst参照型(`const Address&`)が好ましいです。値型(`Address`)では比較のたびにオブジェクト・コピーと破棄が行われてしまいます。
- セマンティクス上、ラムダ式の戻値型は`int`ではなく`bool`が好ましいです。好みの問題もありますが、`return`文の比較式から推論させる（戻り値型は省略）した方がシンプルです。
- 比較演算に「より大きい`>`」を利用した場合、降順ソートが行われます。この振る舞いがあなたの意図通りなら大丈夫です。